# onClick not working on MUI responsive drawer

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, remix.run

I have imported responsive drawer from Material UI, [from here](https://codesandbox.io/s/6ns5ql?file=/demo.tsx:0-6048)

In this example there's a listItemButton, I want to use onClick on this, but I'm unable to do so

This is my file in the Remix, App/Components/Sidebar.tsx

```
import * as React from "react";
import AppBar from "@mui/material/AppBar";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import CssBaseline from "@mui/material/CssBaseline";
import Divider from "@mui/material/Divider";
import Drawer from "@mui/material/Drawer";
import IconButton from "@mui/material/IconButton";
import InboxIcon from "@mui/icons-material/MoveToInbox";
import List from "@mui/material/List";
import ListItem from "@mui/material/ListItem";
import ListItemButton from "@mui/material/ListItemButton";
import ListItemIcon from "@mui/material/ListItemIcon";
import ListItemText from "@mui/material/ListItemText";
import MailIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Mail";
import MenuIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Menu";
import Toolbar from "@mui/material/Toolbar";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";

const drawerWidth = 240;

interface Props {
  /**
   * Injected by the documentation to work in an iframe.
   * You won't need it on your project.
   */
  window?: () => Window;
}

export default function ResponsiveDrawer(props: Props) {
  const { window } = props;
  const [mobileOpen, setMobileOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleDrawerToggle = () => {
    setMobileOpen(!mobileOpen);
  };

  const drawer = (
    <div>
      <Toolbar />

      <Divider />
      <List>
        {["Dashboard"].map((text, index) => (
          <ListItem key={text} disablePadding>
            <ListItemButton onClick={() => console.log("clicked!")}>
              <ListItemIcon>
                {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary={text} />
            </ListItemButton>
          </ListItem>
        ))}
      </List>
      <Divider />
      <List>
        {["Clients", "Users", "Events"].map((text, index) => (
          <ListItem key={text} disablePadding>
            <ListItemButton>
              <ListItemIcon>
                {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary={text} />
            </ListItemButton>
          </ListItem>
        ))}
      </List>
    </div>
  );

  const container =
    window !== undefined ? () => window().document.body : undefined;

  return (
    <Box sx={{ display: "flex", pointerEvents: "all" }}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AppBar
        position="fixed"
        sx={{
          width: { sm: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)` },
          ml: { sm: `${drawerWidth}px`, pointerEvents: "all" },
        }}
      >
        <Toolbar sx={{ backgroundColor: "#2A2F55", pointerEvents: "all" }}>
          <IconButton
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="open drawer"
            edge="start"
            onClick={() => handleDrawerToggle}
            sx={{ mr: 2, display: { sm: "none" }, pointerEvents: "all" }}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="h6" noWrap component="div">
            Responsive drawer
          </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <Box
        component="nav"
        sx={{
          width: { sm: drawerWidth },
          flexShrink: { sm: 0 },
          pointerEvents: "all",
        }}
        aria-label="mailbox folders"
      >
        {/* The implementation can be swapped with js to avoid SEO duplication of links. */}
        <Drawer
          container={container}
          variant="temporary"
          open={mobileOpen}
          onClose={handleDrawerToggle}
          ModalProps={{
            keepMounted: true, // Better open performance on mobile.
          }}
          sx={{
            display: { xs: "block", sm: "none" },
            "& .MuiDrawer-paper": {
              boxSizing: "border-box",
              width: drawerWidth,
            },
            pointerEvents: "all",
          }}
        >
          {drawer}
        </Drawer>
        <Drawer
          variant="permanent"
          sx={{
            display: { xs: "none", sm: "block" },
            "& .MuiDrawer-paper": {
              boxSizing: "border-box",
              width: drawerWidth,
              pointerEvents: "all",
            },
          }}
          open
        >
          {drawer}
        </Drawer>
      </Box>
      <Box
        component="main"
        sx={{
          flexGrow: 1,
          p: 3,
          width: { sm: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`, pointerEvents: "all" },
        }}
      >
        <Toolbar />
        <Typography paragraph>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
          eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Rhoncus
          dolor purus non enim praesent elementum facilisis leo vel. Risus at
          ultrices mi tempus imperdiet. Semper risus in hendrerit gravida rutrum
          quisque non tellus. Convallis convallis tellus id interdum velit
          laoreet id donec ultrices. Odio morbi quis commodo odio aenean sed
          adipiscing. Amet nisl suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies
         
        </Typography>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

and this is my App/routes/index.tsx file in the remix js

```
import Sidebar from "~/components/sidebar";

export default function Index() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Sidebar></Sidebar>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have tried logging if this event fires but I'm not getting any console.log statement

Comment: If you check in the example you've sent, once you add onClick handler everything works correctly. Please provide your example with the non working code part so we can have a look

Comment: @DamianBusz sure let me edit my question

Comment: The on click handler works fine, there is no issue here.  I do notice however there are two separate listItemButtons that you will need to add the on click handler to.  I believe that's why you think it's not working

Comment: @RobTerrell I've tried adding onClick on both but no luck. I've edited my question can you please check now?

Comment: can you provide a sandbox url or jsfiddle link with your code?
also you are clicking on 'Dashboard' or 'Clients, Users, Events' options?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-sammet-khro0m?file=/demo.tsx

Comment: works just fine not sure why you're having trouble with it

Comment: @AjeetChauhan it's literally in the question

Comment: @RobTerrell That's the original code, I'm asking for url of saadi's code, so that i can edit and correct it.

Comment: @AjeetChauhan yes let me share it in a moment

Comment: @Saadi codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-sammet-khro0m?file=/demo.tsx view this demo it works fine I forked your sandbox

Comment: @RobTerrell I think there's something wrong with the app structure, You are right this demo works good. I am unable to make an exact structure of my project on code sandbox.